# French developer looking to access German PlayStore from France

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google, localization

I'm working for a French app, we just launch our app in Germany, so I would like to access the German PlayStore from France to be able to see our ranking and the other app. 
If you have a way to access a foreign PlayStore without need to use a different credit card, it'll be amazing.

Thanks !

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2155761

Comment: Do you just want to see how it's doing, or are you also planning to download it? Do you mind sharing a link to the app?